# Did I compute this limit correctly?

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to find $\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+} x^{x^x}$.  Here is my solution.

Let $u=x^x$  $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}x^u$

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}x^x$=$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}e^{x\text{ln}(x)}$

Using L'Hopital's rule, I can show that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}x\text{ln}(x)=0$, thereore $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}e^{x\text{ln}(x)}=1=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}u$

Thus, the first limit is $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}x^1=0$

So the limit is 0.  Did I get this correct?

Comment: SHWEET!  Thanks a liot

Comment: This depends on how you define $x^{x^x}$. $x^{(x^x)}$ gives your answer, but $(x^x)^x$ gives another answer.

Comment: the question was simply $x^{x^x]$.  No parentheses

Comment: You can however get $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} (x^x)^x = 1$ directly by looking at $u^x \rightarrow 1^0 = 1$ instead.

Comment: I would assume that the expression represents $x^{(x^x)}$ since $(x^x)^x$ could be written more simply as $x^{x^2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say you got the right answer for the wrong reasons. You **cannot** treat the exponent as a separate variable $u$ which approaches $1$ independently of $x \to 0^+$.

In simple terms, every $x$ must approach $0$ at the same time. To illustrate this fact, consider

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{x}$$
This is (clearly!) equal to one, but if we let $u=x$, write $\lim_{u \to 0} u/x$ and let $u \to 0$ keeping $x$ fixed, then the limit is $0/x = 0$... What?

The problem here is that it is *impossible* to let $u \to 0$ while $x \not\to 0$. The variable $u$ depends entirely on $x$! Similarly, in your question to find that $u \to 1$ you are taking $x \to 0^+$, but then you still have $x$ approaching zero later. This does not, in general, produce valid results.

Try using your $a = e^{\ln(a)}$ trick twice. You should come up with a messy, but tractable limit which evaluates to $0$.

Here's a big hint:

$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^{x^x} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{\ln (x^{x^x})} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{x^x \ln{x}} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{e^{ln{x^x \ln{x}}}}
$$

Comment: OK, thanks!  I will try that.

Comment: You actually can do the two limits seperate in this case, since $u\rightarrow 1$ and $x^y$ is continuous in the point $(0,1)$.

Comment: so I basically have to compute the limit of $$ e^{ln(x)}^{e^xln(x)} $$

Comment: The answer is 0, as per Maple and MATLAB.  I got 0 as the answer after using your hint.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking is correct. I would be more careful to write some of the stuff there, though, like "$\lim_{x \to 0^+} u $", for example. Your new variable is $u$, so instead of that, it would be better to put "$\lim_{u \to 1} u = 1 $", which is pretty much useless, since you already found out that $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^x = 1$. Other thing that bothered me a little: "$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^1$", in the end. See that $x^x$ is **not** $1$ in general. To justify it better, I would only write, informally: *$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^{x^x} = 0$, because $x \to 0$ and $x^x \to 1$, and $0^1 = 0$.*

Answer (score 0):

Well you seem to apply the rule that *if $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = A, \lim_{x \to a}g(x) = B$ then $\lim_{x \to a}\{f(x)\}^{g(x)} = A^{B}$*. This is valid but only when $A > 0$ and $B$ is finite. Here $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x^{x}$ and clearly then $A = 0, B = 1$ so the rule can't be applied directly.

Rather we just proceed by taking logs. Consider the expression $v = x^{x}\log x$. As mentioned in the question $x^{x} \to 1$ as $x \to 0$ and we know that $\log x \to -\infty$ as $x \to 0$ so that $v = x^{x}\log x \to -\infty$ as $x \to 0$. It follows that $x^{x^{x}} = e^{v} \to 0$ as $v \to -\infty$.